# Is it possible to make content of transparent div fully visible?

Tags: css

Is it possible? If it's not possible can someone give me some good workaround?

This fiddle will explain my problem very clrearly

http://jsfiddle.net/9AWdz/

Comment: To clarify, you are wanting headerOut to be hidden, but headerIn to be visible? This isn't possible. Hiding an element hides all its child elements. If you give some more detail about what you're trying to achieve then someone can probably help you but as it is I don't know what workaround you need because I have no idea what you are trying to do :X

Comment: I'm trying to make header in black color and make it semi-transparent, but all elements on the header like logo and buttons to be fully visible.

Comment: Ah, then use rgba with a fallback to a tileable PNG with transparency for older browsers. Not worth worrying about IE 6, it's not supported anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this structure:

```
<div id="headerOut">
    <div id="headerIn"></div>
</div>
<div id="normalRed"></div>
```

You can't do it with the `opacity` setting, because `headerOut`s opacity is applied on top of what `headerIn`s opacity is.  `headerIn` can be less opaque than `headerOut`, but never more.

However, you can *simulate* the desired effect by carefully setting `color` and `background` with `rgba()`, and by carefully setting the opacity of child elements.

For example:

```
#headerOut {
    background-color:   rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
    color:              rgba(0,   0, 0, 0.4);
}
#headerOut > img {
    opacity:            0.4;
}
#headerIn, #normalRed {
    background-color:   red;
    color:              black;
    opacity:            1;
}
```

For IE 8 and below, just let those users view a less flashy version of the site, or patch the effect like so (using IE's conditional comments):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    #headerOut {
        background-color: #AFA;
        color: #888;
    }
    #headerOut > img {
        filter: alpha(opacity='40');
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

[**See this in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9AWdz/5/)

---

Pretty much anything else requires javascript.  EG:

1. Using the original layout...
2. Have jQuery, etc. clone the `headerIn` node, append the clone to the document body, and then overlay it directly upon the original node.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work on IE8 and less. jQuery method sounds what I need? But what is optimal way of doing it? having a div that is semi-transparent and placing it every time window is resized seems kinda dumb. Can you give me some idea?

Comment: Updated the answer to also work on IE8 or less.  For JS / jQuery kludges (not recommended), open another question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [rgba](http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/) for your background

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9AWdz/2/

Comment: ps - content contained within any element to which css opacity is applied will inherit that same level of opacity whereas rgba only affects the element to which it is directly applied and is not inherited by contained sub-content